# New peer - can't ping from server to it, and no handshake

Tags: wireguard

I needed to change the current peer to a new peer.
For that I changed the `wg0.conf` file from this:

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = <wg_server_private_key>
Address = 10.8.0.22/24

[Peer]
PublicKey = <old_peer_public_key>
AllowedIPs = 10.8.0.0/24
Endpoint = <old_ec2_public_ip>
```

to this:

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = <wg_server_private_key>
Address = 10.8.0.22/24

[Peer]
PublicKey = <new_peer_public_key> 
AllowedIPs = 10.8.0.0/24
Endpoint = <new_ec2_public_ip>
```

And the `wg0.conf` file on the new peer (new ec2 instance) looks like this:

```
[Interface]
Address = 10.8.0.33/24 #old peer was 10.8.0.11
ListenPort = 51820
PrivateKey = <old_peer_private_ip>

[Peer]
PublicKey = <wg_server_public_ip>
AllowedIPs = 10.8.0.22/32
Endpoint = <some_ip>
```

so only changing the relevant IPs. The new peer tunnel IP is `10.8.0.33` instead of `10.8.0.11` of the old peer.

I allowed UDP port `51820` in the inbound rules of the EC2 instance.

But then when I do `ping 10.8.0.33` nothing happens.
When I change back to the old config of the old peer, then pinging `10.8.0.11` works again.
Why? I must've missed something to configure on the new EC2 instance but can't find out what